# Getting tbb linker errors when including the <execution> header

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker, tbb

I have been writing a visualisation tool using OpenGL. It has been compiling and linking just fine (using gcc 11.2.0) until I recently installed the [Linux dependencies for OpenVDB](https://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/dependencies.html) (listed under *Using UNIX apt-get*). I am now getting linker errors that I have narrowed down to the inclusion of the `<execution>` header file:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `tbb::detail::d1::execution_slot(tbb::detail::d1::execution_data const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb6detail2d114execution_slotERKNS1_14execution_dataE[_ZN3tbb6detail2d114execution_slotERKNS1_14execution_dataE]+0x18): undefined reference to `tbb::detail::r1::execution_slot(tbb::detail::d1::execution_data const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `tbb::detail::d1::current_thread_index()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3tbb6detail2d120current_thread_indexEv[_ZN3tbb6detail2d120current_thread_indexEv]+0x12): undefined reference to `tbb::detail::r1::execution_slot(tbb::detail::d1::execution_data const*)'
```

The above is from the following minimal example.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
```

I have tried linking TBB with my project like so:

```
# Find and link TBB.
find_package(TBB REQUIRED)
include_directories(${TBB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${TBB_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${TBB_DEFINITIONS})
if(NOT TBB_FOUND)
    message("Error: TBB not found")
endif(NOT TBB_FOUND)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${TBB_LIBRARIES})
```

...and also adding the `-ltbb` linker flag (as per the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67854770/i-do-not-use-tbb-but-i-get-linker-errors-related-to-tbb) post) using

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -ltbb")
```

However, this does not solve the issue.

What I find particularly strange is that I didn't use to have to link against `tbb` despite having included the `<excution>` header all along. Only after installing the OpenVDB dependencies has this become an issue.

Can anyone advise me on how to solve this (either by appropriately linking `tbb`, or not having to link it at all, as was the case before)? Any form of insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to successfully link `tbb` as follows:

```
find_package(TBB REQUIRED COMPONENTS tbb)

add_executable(test main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test tbb)
```

Although I am still clueless as to why I suddenly needed to link with `tbb`, considering I previously didn't need to.

Comment: Just had the same experience: still clueless as to why I suddenly needed to link with tbb, considering I previously didn't need to. Same here.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling `libtbb-dev` also works and dont require editing the `CMakeFiles.txt`.